# why debugging is not working in reactnative project ?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Runtime is not ready for debugging. Make sure Packager server is running.

i tried many things but no use.

[image: ios-emulator]

Comment: Could you post the console output please. Also, what version of react-native and what does your `AppDelegate.m` look like?

Comment: here is a link 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4wqw6clllbxdbz/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-01%20at%207.54.35%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: Did does this load correctly http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui ? What does the page say?

Comment: React Native JS code runs inside this Chrome tab.

Press ⌘⌥J to open Developer Tools. Enable Pause On Caught Exceptions for a better debugging experience.

Status: Debugger session #10009 active.


yes working properly but after sometime it gives such message : :
`code`
8debugger-ui:28 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=debugger&name=Chrome' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
`code`

Comment: Last thing. XCode should open a terminal window, what does it say? it should be something like `transformed 664/664 (100%)`

Comment: here is a link 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/62ojzwsc5vy9gje/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-01%20at%208.13.48%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0x95m0hljyipcr/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-01%20at%208.22.55%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: i guess it may be something with watchman ,i am not sure , i am just so new to reactnative environment

Comment: the `[error not open]` is not what we see, but not sure why that's happening. Try reloading the simulator. Some times I see that error and I actually have to restart the app on the device. and also restarting the javascript console. I think there might be a bug.

Comment: Just saw your other screen shot. try `watchman watch-del-all` & `npm start -- --reset-cache` to clear the caches

Answer (score 1):

i thank you for ur patience it finally worked using :: npm link

Comment: Great!  I'm glad you were able to figure it out.